# MSBUILD error where folder contains more than one solution file

Tags: msbuild, ccnet-config

I'm trying to set up CCNET and I've run into a problem.

My builds are failing and I'm getting this error

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.
```

In my configuration file `ccnet.config` my `msbuild` block is as follows

```
  <msbuild>
  <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
   <workingDirectory>C:\example\directory</workingDirectory>
  <projectFile>ExampleSolution.sln</projectFile>
  <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /v:quiet
   /p:Configuration=Debug
   /p:ReferencePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.10\bin\net-2.0\"
  </buildArgs>
  <targets>ReBuild</targets>
  <timeout>600</timeout>
  </msbuild>
```

In this case, C:\example\directory has multiple solution files.  Even though I specified the project file I'm still getting that error.

Comment: What version of cruise control? Also, silly question, but you don't have multiple msbuild tasks do you (where you might be looking at the wrong one...)?

Comment: Version 1.6.7981.1.  And nope, I only have one msbuild task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify **what to build** in the sln group.

```
msbuild SlnFolders.sln /t:NotInSolutionfolder:Rebuild;NewFolder\InSolutionFolder:Clean
```

So in CC.NET, add the `/t` parameter in the `<buildArgs>` tag.

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Comment: I ended up just having to add ExampleSolution.sln right after <buildArgs> and also take the last "\" out of the ReferencePath