# Microsoft visual studio: "error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one..."

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This happens each time after I run my code in Visual Studio on my mac.

`MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.`

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Check your project root folder for duplicate .sln or .csproj files

Comment: Try to specify a file which you want to build. You can refer to [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300654/8335151) or [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610424/8335151).